# Query Manager: Trying to bring in the Manager's name

Tags: peoplesoft

I'm using PeopleSoft's Query Manager to build a new hire report that brings in the manager's name. Unfortunately the Job - EE table captures the reports to position and not the manager. In an effort to get the manager's name I have to link to the Job - EE table again, linking the two tables with A.Reports_To equal to G.Position_NBR. So now I have two views of the Job - EE table. The problem is that I'm looking at a date range (Jan 1 2018 to present) and I haven't been able to figure out how to bring in the manager at precisely the same time as the hire date.  I seem to be bringing in all the managers who have been in the Reports_To position prior to the ending effective date.  I think this is because the Job - EE table links to the position (reports to) instead of an actual employee. The person occupying the reports to often changes.

Anyone have any suggestions?
**EDITED to update**:
Here are some pics of the various tables, query manager criteria, etc:
[image: Criteria]
[image: Subquery Criteria]
[image: Tables]

**Here's the SQL**:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT A.EMPLID, B.NAME, (CONVERT(CHAR(10),A.EFFDT,121)), A.DEPTID, D.DESCR, C.DESCR, A.ANNUAL_RT, E.DESCR, G.EMPLID, G.POSITION_NBR, Concat( H.FIRST_NAME,' ', H.LAST_NAME) 
  FROM PS_JOB A, PS_EMPLMT_SRCH_QRY A1, PS_PERSONAL_DATA B, PS_DEPT_TBL D, PS_SET_CNTRL_REC D2, PS_JOBCODE_TBL C, PS_SET_CNTRL_REC C2, PS_LOCATION_TBL E, PS_SET_CNTRL_REC E2, PS_JOB G, PS_EMPLMT_SRCH_QRY G1, PS_NAMES H, PS_PERALL_SEC_QRY H1 
  WHERE ( D.DEPTID = A.DEPTID 
    AND D2.SETCNTRLVALUE = A.BUSINESS_UNIT 
    AND D2.RECNAME = 'DEPT_TBL' 
    AND D2.SETID = D.SETID 
    AND C.JOBCODE = A.JOBCODE 
    AND C2.SETCNTRLVALUE = A.BUSINESS_UNIT 
    AND C2.RECNAME = 'JOBCODE_TBL' 
    AND C2.SETID = C.SETID 
    AND E.LOCATION = A.LOCATION 
    AND E2.SETCNTRLVALUE = A.BUSINESS_UNIT 
    AND E2.RECNAME = 'LOCATION_TBL' 
    AND E2.SETID = E.SETID 
    AND A.EMPLID = A1.EMPLID 
    AND A.EMPL_RCD = A1.EMPL_RCD 
    AND A1.OPRID = 'XXXXXXXX' 
    AND G.EMPLID = G1.EMPLID 
    AND G.EMPL_RCD = G1.EMPL_RCD 
    AND G1.OPRID = 'XXXXXXXX' 
    AND H.EMPLID = H1.EMPLID 
    AND H1.OPRID = 'XXXXXXXX' 
    AND ( A.EFFDT = (SELECT MIN( F.EFFDT) 
  FROM PS_JOB F, PS_EMPLMT_SRCH_QRY F1 
  WHERE F.EMPLID = F1.EMPLID 
    AND F.EMPL_RCD = F1.EMPL_RCD 
    AND F1.OPRID = 'XXXXXXXX' 
    AND ( A.EMPLID = F.EMPLID 
     AND A.EMPL_RCD = F.EMPL_RCD 
     AND A.ACTION IN ('HIR','REH','REI') 
     AND A.EFFDT BETWEEN :1 AND :2 )) 
     AND A.ACTION IN ('HIR','REH','REI') 
     AND B.EMPLID = A.EMPLID 
     AND D.EFFDT = 
        (SELECT MAX(D_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_DEPT_TBL D_ED 
        WHERE D.SETID = D_ED.SETID 
          AND D.DEPTID = D_ED.DEPTID 
          AND D_ED.EFFDT <= A.EFFDT) 
     AND C.EFFDT = 
        (SELECT MAX(C_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_JOBCODE_TBL C_ED 
        WHERE C.SETID = C_ED.SETID 
          AND C.JOBCODE = C_ED.JOBCODE 
          AND C_ED.EFFDT <= A.EFFDT) 
     AND E.EFFDT = 
        (SELECT MAX(E_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_LOCATION_TBL E_ED 
        WHERE E.SETID = E_ED.SETID 
          AND E.LOCATION = E_ED.LOCATION 
          AND E_ED.EFFDT <= A.EFFDT) 
     AND A.REPORTS_TO = G.POSITION_NBR 
     AND G.EMPLID = H.EMPLID 
     AND H.EFFDT = 
        (SELECT MAX(H_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_NAMES H_ED 
        WHERE H.EMPLID = H_ED.EMPLID 
          AND H.NAME_TYPE = H_ED.NAME_TYPE) 
     AND G.EFFDT = 
        (SELECT MAX(G_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_JOB G_ED 
        WHERE G.EMPLID = G_ED.EMPLID 
          AND G.EMPL_RCD = G_ED.EMPL_RCD 
          AND G_ED.EFFDT <= ( A.LAST_HIRE_DT)+1) 
    AND G.EFFSEQ = 
        (SELECT MAX(G_ES.EFFSEQ) FROM PS_JOB G_ES 
        WHERE G.EMPLID = G_ES.EMPLID 
          AND G.EMPL_RCD = G_ES.EMPL_RCD 
          AND G.EFFDT = G_ES.EFFDT) ))
```

Comment: Does your PS_JOB not have SUPERVISOR_ID?

Comment: Also A1.OPRID is 7 X's long, while G1.OPRID and H1.OPRID are 6 X's long. Is this intentional?

Comment: I don't have a PS_JOB table; we have a JOB - EE table and we have a (probably custom) JOB_VW table, which has the SUPERVISOR_ID, but it's not filled out (when run, it comes out blank).

Comment: No, the 7X's were not intentional.

Comment: @phlegon_of_thralles, JOB - EE is probably an alias for the PS_JOB table, as your SQL does show PS_JOB. I'll try to get the where condition correct via Query Manager and get back to you.

Comment: My mistake Peter. In any event, our Supervisor_ID is not filled out. :(

Answer (score 3):

In addition to this being a lot easier if your institution/company would just use the SUPERVISOR_ID field, it seems your problem is:

> I seem to be bringing in all the managers who have been in the Reports_To position prior to the ending effective date

This is because, in your initial select on PS_JOB(A), you only limit the effective date(EFFDT) to your input range [:1,:2] for records with an action in ('HIR','REH','REI').

```
 AND ( A.EFFDT BETWEEN :1 AND :2  
 AND A.ACTION IN ('HIR','REH','REI')
 ... )
```

This will select every record with an EFFDT in the interval, while you only want one, presumably the first(MIN).

```
AND ( A.EFFDT = (SELECT MIN(A_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_JOB A_ED
                    WHERE A_ED.EMPLID = A.EMPLID
                      AND A_ED.EMPL_RCD = A.EMPL_RCD
                      AND A.ED.EFFDT BETWEEN :1 AND :2
                      AND A_ED.ACTION IN ('HIR', 'REH', 'REI')
... )
```

This will probably fix the problem, but keep in mind you may also have to account for the effective sequence (EFFSEQ) to filter one record out.

EDIT: Via Query Manager

1. Go to criteria and edit the A.EFFDT criterium.
2. Condition type should be 'equal to' and Expression 2 type should be subquery.
3. Define/Edit subquery
4. Select Job EE as record, click OK on the messagebox about effective date.
5. Select EFFDT as field under Query tab, Edit field and select Min aggregate. Here you get the error about 'aggregate field but is being used in non-having criteria'
6. Go to Criteria tab, delete the auto added effdt criterium and add the other criteria, matching the subquery to the main query and the ACTION criteria. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMWSg.png)

[image: Subquery criteria]

Comment: It doesn't seem as though we use SUPERVISOR_ID unfortunately. I can't directly input the SQL - I have to use Query Manager. Because of that I think I'm inputting the expression wrong (I get an error), I do see the SQL though: 

AND ( MIN( A.EFFDT) BETWEEN :1 AND :2 
     AND A.ACTION IN ('HIR','REH','REI') 
     AND B.EMPLID = A.EMPLID

Comment: I get the following error:

A SQL error occurred. Please consult your system log for details.
Error in running query because of SQL Error, Code=8602, Message=[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference. [Microsoft][SQL Server (50,380)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow; how does adding another look (a third) at the Job EE table fix the second look at the Job EE table (the one where I get the manager's data from)? I tried your solution, but it's still bringing in extra people - it's bringing in people who were in the hiring manager's position prior to the search terms (even if they termed before the date criteria.

Comment: I've updated the original post with updated SQL, pictures of the criteria, etc. I appreciate the time/effort you've put into trying to help me.

Comment: The additional join was to limit the amount of records for that interval to 1 per person. Which in turn should limit the amount of managers. I wish I had a database using the reports_to and position_nbr fields. Could you maybe setup a test example in SQLFiddle?

Comment: I'm not sure - I don't know what SQLFiddle is, unfortunately.

Comment: It's one of many online database test environments. SQLFiddle seems to be down though but there's also db-fiddle.com and other alternatives.